# Converter int em binário

Tags: python

Preciso converter uma variável np.array (300,1) em valores binários. Criei um array teste, mas a função decimal_para_binario está me retornando ['1'].

Quero converter todos os valores da variável *teste* para binário.

```
teste = np.array([[1],[2],[0],[-3]]) #shape(4,1)

def decimal_para_binario(saida_desejada):
    for i in range(len(saida_desejada)):
        binario = []
        while len(binario) < len(saida_desejada):

            saida_desejada = (bin(int(saida_desejada[i]))[2:])
        
            binario.append(saida_desejada)
        
        #print(saida_desejada)
        #break
        return binario
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

teste = np.array([[1],[2],[0],[-3]]) #shape(4,1)

def decimal_para_binario(saida_desejada):
    binario = []
    for i in range(len(saida_desejada)):
        binario.append(bin(int(saida_desejada[i])))
    return binario
        
print(decimal_para_binario(teste))
```

Isto irá imprimir: ['0b1', '0b10', '0b0', '-0b11']

Ainda mais simples:

```
def decimal_para_binario(saida_desejada):
    return list(map(bin, map(int, saida_desejada)))
```